# Not getting text from EditText on ActionBar button click

Tags: android, android-edittext, android-view, layout-inflater

I have used ActionBar in my app. I want to get value from an EditText i.e on other Layout. I have tried to get that layout and then getting the EditText value.

Code to get the layout in which EditText is

```
public View textInputChecks() {

    LayoutInflater mLayoutInflater = getLayoutInflater();
    View textQrView = mLayoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.text_qr, null);
    return textQrView;
}
```

Code for ActionBar button click

```
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {

    // TODO This is really needed to make app icon a toggle of nav drawer.
    if (mDrawerToggle.onOptionsItemSelected(item)) {
        return true;
    } else {

        switch (item.getItemId()) {

        case R.id.action_ok:
            View textInputView = textInputChecks();
            EditText textInput = (EditText) textInputView.findViewById(R.id.qrTextInput);
            String text = textInput.getText().toString();
            if (text.length()>0) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Ok",
                        Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            } else {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "No Text added",
                        Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
            break;

        default:
            break;
        }
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
```

It always shows "No Text Added" Toast message even if you add text

Comment: Change `View` to `ViewGroup` in that `textInputChecks` function

Comment: shows an error for null value in ViewGroup textQrView = mLayoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.text_qr, null);

Comment: did you cast also that `ViewGroup`? And try as well `LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService( Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE );` instead your inflater

Comment: Still the same. No errors and not getting text

Comment: Did you also change `View textInputView = textInputChecks();`  to ViewGroup?

Comment: yes. I have changed that